# rotate 2D array counterclockwise about its center while maintaining the array size

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

for example, if the 2d image array is

```
1,10
2,20
3,30
4,40
```

so the size would be: `int[][] table = new int[table.length][table[0].length];`

from this point of view: table[# of columns][# of rows]

if I want to rotate counter clockwise by 90 degrees it would be

```
10,20,30,40
1,2,3,4
```

but the size would be [4][2] and I want it to stay [2][4]

the output I'm looking for is:

```
0,0
20, 30
2,3
0,0
```

I've seen how rotation is done but those methods change the size of the width and height. is there a way to accomplish this? TIA

Comment: You did not put in any code you have tried to do this.  Please edit your question and add any code you have done and where you think it has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way I think is to use the for loop to get result.
Why don't you try the for loop for output?
The code below is an example.

```
   for (int i = table[0].length; i < 0; i--) {
        for(int j = 0; j < table.length; j++) {
            print(a[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

I thought so, but I don't know if I got your intention well.